# how do I make a regex-inspired string function?

Tags: c, regex, substring, match

### QUESTION:

Take a look at my "scan" function. That's what decides where in the string a match is. (btw this is EEL code, it's a language that is very C-like). How would I begin to add a regex-like match? My intent is a regex-inspired function as I don't want or need to copy regex behavior exactly. Specifically, I'd like to steal the \d functionality of regex, basically a character class that means "match any character from '0' to '9'.

Example:"abc \d\d\d" to match "abc 123";

Any explanation, helpful tips for beginning to add this kind of functionality is appreciated!

### DETAILS:

Here is my "bidirectional string scanner" function that outputs a substring. It's bidirectional because you have to specify two matches m1 m2, two "how many times do you want to match before stopping?" (called ntimes1 ntimes2) the starting position p1, and of course the string to be scanned (the haystack).

It can move forwards forwards 'ff'
backwards backwards 'bb'
backwards forwards 'bf'
and forwards backwards 'fb'.

**for example, say you want the number before the second occurance of "abc" in:**

*"abc,1,def,4,ghi,5,abc,2,def,6,ghi,3"*

**start at 0, move forward and match "abc" twice, move backwards: match "," twice**

*substring = ",5,abc" (currently the substring includes all match strings)*

**and it works great!**

### CODE:

```
function scan(match,str,p,D,ntimes,mlen,hlen) local(lastp found break restart) (
  D == -1 ? (m=restart=mlen-1; end=-1) : (m=restart=0; end=mlen);
  found=break=0;
  while(p > -1 && p < hlen && !break) (
    //ShowConsoleMsg(sprintf(#, "%i:%i ->  ' %c ' = ' %c '\n", m,p,str_getchar(match, m),str_getchar(str, p)));
    str_getchar(match, m) == str_getchar(str, p) ? m+=D : m=restart;    
    m == end ? (found+=1; m=restart; lastp=p);
    found == ntimes ? break=1 : p+=D;
  );
  ntimes == -1 ? lastp : p;
);

function findpos(m1,m2,DIR,p1,ntimes1,ntimes2) local(adj start p1 p2 len1 len2 dir1 dir2 hlen) (
  hlen = strlen(this);
  len1 = strlen(m1);
  len2 = strlen(m2);
  ntimes1 < 1 ? ntimes1 = -1;
  ntimes2 < 1 ? ntimes2 = -1;

  DIR == 'ff' ? (dir1 =     dir2 = +1; adj=1):
  DIR == 'fb' ? (dir1 = +1; dir2 = -1; adj=1):
  DIR == 'bf' ? (dir1 = -1; dir2 = +1; adj=1):
                (dir1 =     dir2 = -1; adj=len1);

  p1 = scan(m1,this,p1,dir1,ntimes1,len1,hlen);

  DIR == 'ff' ? (p2=p1+len1+dir1; p1+=dir1-len1):
  DIR == 'bf' ? (p2=p1+len1):
                (p2=p1-len1);
  //ShowConsoleMsg(sprintf(#, "%i---------%i\n", p1,p2));
  p2 = scan(m2,this,p2,dir2,ntimes2,len2,hlen);

  dir2 == 1 ?    (p2+=len; this.pos1 = p1; this.pos2 = p2):
  DIR  == 'fb' ? (p2+=len; this.pos1 = p2; this.pos2 = p1):
                          (this.pos1 = p2; this.pos2 = p1);
  //ShowConsoleMsg(sprintf(#, "%i---------%i\n", p1,p2));
  this.substrlen = this.pos2-this.pos1+adj;  
  strcpy_substr(#, this, this.pos1, this.substrlen);
);
```

example of usage:

```
ShowConsoleMsg("");
string  = "C-2=0,C#-2=1,D-2=2,D#-2=3,";

ShowConsoleMsg( sprintf(#, "%s\n",string.findpos(",",",",'ff',8,1,1)) );
ShowConsoleMsg( sprintf(#, "%s\n",string.findpos(",",",",'fb',15,1,1)) );
ShowConsoleMsg( sprintf(#, "%s\n",string.findpos(",",",",'bf',15,1,1)) );
ShowConsoleMsg( sprintf(#, "%s\n",string.findpos(",",",",'bb',21,1,1)) );

ShowConsoleMsg( sprintf(#, "%s\n",string.findpos("1,",",D",'ff',8,1,1)) );
ShowConsoleMsg( sprintf(#, "%s\n",string.findpos(",D","1,",'fb',15,1,1)) );
ShowConsoleMsg( sprintf(#, "%s\n",string.findpos("1,",",D",'bf',15,1,1)) );
ShowConsoleMsg( sprintf(#, "%s\n",string.findpos(",D","1,",'bb',21,1,1)) );

ShowConsoleMsg( sprintf(#, "%s\n",string.findpos("1,",",",'ff',8,1,1)) );
ShowConsoleMsg( sprintf(#, "%s\n",string.findpos(",","1,",'fb',15,1,1)) );
ShowConsoleMsg( sprintf(#, "%s\n",string.findpos("1,",",",'bf',15,1,1)) );
ShowConsoleMsg( sprintf(#, "%s\n",string.findpos(",","1,",'bb',21,1,1)) );

ShowConsoleMsg( sprintf(#, "%s\n",string.findpos(",",",D",'ff',8,1,1)) );
ShowConsoleMsg( sprintf(#, "%s\n",string.findpos(",D",",",'bb',21,1,1)) );
ShowConsoleMsg( sprintf(#, "%s\n",string.findpos(",",",D",'bf',16,1,1)) );
ShowConsoleMsg( sprintf(#, "%s\n",string.findpos(",D",",",'fb',15,1,1)) );
```

output:

```
,D-2=2,
,D-2=2,
,D-2=2,
,D-2=2,
1,D-2=2,D
1,D-2=2,D
1,D-2=2,D
1,D-2=2,D
1,D-2=2,
1,D-2=2,
1,D-2=2,
1,D-2=2,
,D-2=2,D
,D-2=2,D
,D-2=2,D
,D-2=2,D
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't actually run your code but taking a quick look, I think you want to change this line:

```
str_getchar(match, m) == str_getchar(str, p) ? m+=D : m=restart;
```

Right now, it looks for an exact match of the characters. You'd change it so if the search string is the magic character class character, instead of checking an exact thing, it checks a range.

So like

```
char c = str_getchar(match, m);
if(c == magic_thing) {
   char n = str_getchar(str, p);
   (n >= '0' && n <= '9') ? m+=D : m=restart;
else
   c == str_getchar(str, p) ? m +=D : m=restart;
}
```

In there. To do the magic_thing, you might modify str_getchar (or write a wrapper for it) which checks for `\`. If it is there, read the next character too. If it is 'd', return the magic signifier. Otherwise, return the character itself. You might do it a bit differently, but generally I would want to put the \d recognitition in the read string function instead of trying to put it as part of the scan function itself.

Comment: sweet, gonna try out your idea, will get back and check it.